# Differentiate a unknown function

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I been reading The Theoretical Minimum, and I got to symmetries. A potential is defined as
$$
V(q_1,q_2)=V(aq_1-b_2q_2)
$$
and, using the Euler-Lagrangian equation $\dot{p_i}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_i}$ the following equations of motion are defined
$$
\dot{p_1}=-aV'(aq_1-bq_2)
$$
$$
\dot{p_2}=+bV'(aq_1-bq_2)
$$
I am having trouble understanding how he gets to $\dot{p_1}$ and $\dot{p_2}$, in particular how $-a$ and $+b$ are obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a minus sign in your $\dot p$ equation.

The derivative of $V$ is obtained using the chain rule.

$$
\partial_{q_i} V(f(q)) = V’(f(q)) \partial_{q_i}f
$$